# How do I let the user enter a date using elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, user-input

I'm writing a tool to track time spent on projects in Emacs (kind of like timeclock with reporting and more functions).  Short of ripping `org-read-date` out of org-mode, however, I'm unable to find a good way of allowing the user to enter a dates for reporting without requiring that they enter it in the format "2011-04-22T00:00:00", which is not so human-friendly.

Is there an obvious way I'm missing?  If not, can you suggest a not-too-complex way of writing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you can't use `org-read-date`? It also understands human-friendly input formats like "10 Jul 8pm". And org is bundled in recent Emacs.

Comment: I could do that, but I'd have to `(require 'org)` when my code is loaded, and that is a pretty heavy dependency.

Comment: Why not just require it at the last minute in your own `read-date` function, and check for overall availability of org at load/compile time: `(unless (featurep 'org) (error "org not available"))` ?

Comment: `featurep` tests whether org has been required, not whether it is available to require. I'm not sure there's a simple way to do that. Unless I misunderstand what is being attempted here, naturally.

Comment: True, @astine. `(locate-library "org")` would be a better predicate. But with the benefit of 3 more years' experience, I'd now suggest `(eval-when-compile (require 'org))` at the top-level to ensure that `org` is available and that the code compiles cleanly, and `(autoload 'org-read-date "org")` to lazily load it when needed later.

Comment: That is much cleaner. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to tolerate a dependency on the *calendar* package, there's also the function [`calendar-read-date`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specified-Dates.html#Specified-Dates). It's not as fancy as *org-mode*'s prompts, but the *calendar* package may be a more palatable prerequisite.

Comment: I'm not sure that's much more friendly --- it feels all wrong.

Comment: Yes, "not as fancy" was a polite was of saying "not as friendly". Or did you mean the dependency on *calendar* isn't much more friendly than a dependency on *org*? If so, it's just history and longevity that makes me think of *calendar* as more "built-in" than *org*.

Comment: No, I'm much more open to the _dependency_, but the functionality is . . . limited.